# Why the typing is different when specifying props directly on component, or inside another prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

It may seem confusing, but consider the next component ([See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=44&ssc=3&pln=39&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsDcAsAFD8YATzBUACozCEAPABUAfHAC8ufnDjAAdsBgA1FABt8SAFxxZmNXDCM0SQoTMAKAG6HjZ2QEpli2f2p+fiQAD0hYODQITUJ4AElNMHx4FTlMeSccKy0dfSMkSz51Gwg7B0LqMwkIKTl5LzNkdBgAOiaMAFEDJBAkTRTFLKLI6Ni4AG03fOxiPXckAF1lAmIyCiQ6pxy5-K9eAWH2GHwoTTgnK3VpLSSYS-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-AiQheIR2Y4C02k4CR8xmGe2DFmYZaKHRd6wU2T4sZ26rsb2XBAA)):

```
type Props<T> = {
  initValue: T,
  process: (value: T) => T
}

export const Input = <T,>({
  initValue,
  process,
}: Props<T>): React.ReactElement => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(initValue);

  return (
    <input
      value={value as unknown as string}
      onChange={({ target: { value: dirtyValue } }) => {
        const processedValue = process(dirtyValue as unknown as T);

        setValue(processedValue);
      }}
    />
  );
};

() => (
  // fails because value is number, and indexOf doesn't exist on number
  <Input initValue={4} process={value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`} />
);

() => (
  // fails because the return type of process is number, not string
  <Input initValue={'4'} process={value => value.indexOf('4')} />
);

() => (
  // passes because value is string, indexOf exists on string, and process returns string
  <Input initValue={'4'} process={value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`} />
);
```

Ignore the component body itself, the focus is on typing. The goal of this typing is that the component inherits `initValue`'s type inside `process` both in the parameter type, and expected return type.

Now check if I copy the exact same props as the last one (which passes), but spreading:

```
() => (
  // fails because value is type unknown (not sure why)
  <Input {...{initValue: '4', process: value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`}} />
);
```

Now it says that `value` is type `unknown`. Why is that?

Comment: I believe this is because when you wrap your props in object, you are creating new context for TypeScript

Comment: So you want the value param and return type of the process prop to be the same type as the inferred initValue prop?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an imperfection of type inference system. It is not the problem with props per se, because if you write

```
Input({...{initValue: '4', process: value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`}})
```

There is the same error, no JSX or react involved (this code doesn't make much sense, but from the point of view of typescript it's a valid function call).

Not sure exactly why this doesn't work, but there are many work-arounds:

```
<Input<string> {...{initValue: '4', process: value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`}} />
```

```
// The prettiest imho
<Input {...{initValue: '4', process: (value: string) => `${value.indexOf('4')}`}} />
```

```
<Input {...{initValue: '4', process: value => `${value.indexOf('4')}`} as Props<string>} />
```

Anyway not sure why you would write a spread like this without assigning this object to a typed variable beforehand in practice. Unless you're just interested why exactly this happens, in which case I would also like to know a more precise answer :p